# Stripping all content outside <body> & </body> tags (and those tags themselves)

Tags: bash, sed

Note - This is an assignment, instead of the direct answer, please point me in the right direction.

The Assignment is to create a script which takes a path as argument. At this path it will strip away everything outside the body tags of each .html file in that directory, as well as the body tags as well and store them in a new file.

My issue is I cannot for the life of me get away the body-tags. See my bode below.

```
directory=$1
files=$(du -a $directory | find -name "*.html")
for f in $files; do
    file=$f
    outputdata=$(sed -n "/body/,/body/p" $file)
    echo $outputdata
done
```

Any advice?

Comment: ...`du -a`? Why in the...?

Comment: Is the assignment specifically asking you to deal with HTML from the shell, or is it just a poorly designed assignment that assumes standard shell tools like `sed` are appropriate for handling HTML?

Comment: Also, that's the wrong way to get a list of filenames. See the first entry in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (its title talks about `ls`, but the text discusses `find` as well).

Comment: Really, though, the Right Thing is to use a tool like xsltproc or xmlstarlet that natively knows how to parse markup.

Comment: Also, you're missing lots of quotes; see http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Be sure you test your code against filenames with spaces before you call it finished/correct.

Comment: If you want to look at ways the naive `sed` approach gets it wrong, by the way, try having extra `body` tags inside of `<!-- -->` comments (which a compliant parser would ignore), or inside of a namespace which is neither the default nor XHTML (which, again, a compliant parser would ignore).

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a Q&Hint site. The goal of an answer is to be helpful not just to the person who asked, but to anyone else with the same problem; requesting intentional vagueness thus works against the site's ability to fulfil its intended use.

Comment: (Back on the topic of using `sed` and similar regex-based tools for HTML; there's an answer that's something of a classic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122)

Comment: Every time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See, for example, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. Edit your question to include sample input and expected output if you need help. It sounds like you just want to process the files in a given directory, not find all the files under that directory's sub-directories - is that correct?

Comment: @EdMorton, good point -- if we don't need to recurse, then it's just `for filename in "$1"/*.html; do`, and the `find` can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you don't want an answer, but there's a conflict innate in guiding someone to a fully correct answer while providing only hints (which are, by nature, easy to misinterpret).

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  xmllint --html --xmlout "$filename" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//body' -c './*'
done < <(find "$1" -name '*.html' -print0)
```

Notes:

- Using `find -print0` emits a NUL-delimited stream; `IFS= read -r -d ''` parses out individual elements of this stream in a manner that's robust against all possible characters which can exist in filenames (which includes spaces, newlines, etc). See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).
- The `<()` substitution is a ksh extension adopted by bash, zsh, and others. Be sure your shell is `#!/bin/bash` (or similar) rather than `#!/bin/sh`; its benefit over a traditional pipeline is that the shell session running `xmllint` is the same one that's still active after the loop, allowing you to set variables and make other state changes without having them discarded when the pipeline exits (see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)).
- Using `xmllint --html --xmlout` converts from HTML to XML, to ensure that XML-aware tools can correctly parse your content.
- `xmlstarlet sel` takes an XPath expression; `//body` is an XPath expression that finds a body tag in the default namespace anywhere in your document. (Supporting body tags in the XHTML namespace is an exercise for the reader). See [the XMLStarlet documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html), and [the specification for XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).
- `-c ./*` tells xmlstarlet to emit a *copy* (hence the `-c`) of everything matching the XPath expression `./*`, which refers to contents *under* the item directly matched (thus, everything inside the body, but not the body element itself).